# SQL join - How to select all the distinct values that appear in one table and not another

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have 2 SQL tables. The 2 tables share 2 columns: `external_id` of type `int` and `permission` of type `text`:

```
CREATE TABLE A (
    id              serial PRIMARY KEY,
    external_id     int,
    permission      text,          
    something       int,           
    rather          text
);

CREATE TABLE B (
    id              serial PRIMARY KEY,
    external_id     int,
    permission      text,          
    random          int,           
    life_story      text
);
```

I want to `select` all the distinct combinations of `external_id`, `permission` in table `A` that DO NOT exist in table `B` `AND` vice-versa, all the distinct combinations of `external_id`, `permission` in table `B` that DO NOT exist in table `A`

To clarify the query I'm trying to write, I turn to examples: 
If the tables look like this:

```
mwe=# select * from A;
 id | external_id | permission | something | rather
----+-------------+------------+-----------+---------
  1 |           1 | X          |      1111 | bla bla
  2 |           1 | P          |      1111 | bla bla
  3 |           2 | X          |      1111 | bla bla
(3 rows)

mwe=# select * from B;
 id | external_id | permission | random | life_story
----+-------------+------------+--------+------------
  1 |           1 | X          |     41 | bla bla
  2 |           1 | P          |     15 | bla bla
  3 |           2 | X          |     46 | bla bla
(3 rows)
```

The result of my query will be empty. because the distinct `external_id`, `permission` tuples for both tables are:

```
1| X
1| P
2| X
```

If the state of the tables is:

```
mwe=# select * from A;
 id | external_id | permission | something | rather
----+-------------+------------+-----------+---------
  1 |           1 | X          |      1111 | bla bla
  2 |           1 | P          |      1111 | bla bla
  3 |           2 | P          |      1111 | bla bla
  4 |           2 | X          |      1111 | bla bla
  5 |           2 | X          |      2222 | bla bla
(5 rows)

mwe=# select * from B;
 id | external_id | permission | random | life_story
----+-------------+------------+--------+------------
  1 |           1 | X          |     41 | bla bla
  2 |           1 | X          |     99 | one day along time ago
  3 |           1 | P          |     15 | bla bla
  4 |        NULL | X          |     46 | bla bla
  5 |           2 | X          |     46 | bla bla
(5 rows)
```

the result of my query should be:

```
2   | P
NULL| X
```

because the distinct `external_id`, `permission` tuples for table `A` are:

```
 1| X              # id=1
 1| P              # id=2
 2| P              # id=3
 2| X              # id=4,5
```

and the distinct `external_id`, `permission` tuples for table `B` are:

```
 1   | X           # id=1,2
 1   | P           # id=3
 NULL| X           # id=4
 2   | X           # id=5
```

since `2| P` appears in the tuples we listed for table `A` and does NOT appear in the tuples we listed for table `B`, I want it to be returned as a result of my desired select query.

And since `NULL| X` appears in the tuples we listed for table `B` and does NOT appear in the tuples we listed for table `A`, I want it to be returned as a result of my desired select query

For every other distinct `external_id`, `permission` tuples in any of the two tables, there is a matching tuple on the other table:

```
 1   | X           # table A id=1 table B id=1,2
 1   | P           # table A id=2 table B id=3
 2   | X           # table A id=4,5 table B id=5
```

I'm using Postgres 9.6

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT IN` on each side, and then `UNION` both sides:

```
select distinct external_id, permission
  from a
  where (external_id, permission) not in (
    select external_id, permission from b
  )
  or external_id is null and permission not in (
    select permission from b where permission is null    
  )
union  
select distinct external_id, permission
  from b
  where (external_id, permission) not in (
    select external_id, permission from a
  )
  or external_id is null and permission not in (
    select permission from a where permission is null    
  );
```

Result:

```
external_id  permission
-----------  ----------
2            P         
<null>       X
```